# need help in understanding a research paper.... specifically related to KL divergence

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, kullback-leibler

In this paper 
https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2002654

specifically section 2.4.

I understood that Review rating is modelled as random variable with guassian distribution with mean as wt * or.

I am having trouble understanding the next page i.e starting part of page 1499. Specifically 
 this part 
"We further incorporate aspect frequency as a prior
knowledge to define the distribution of µ and Σ.
Specifically, the distribution of µ and Σ is defined
based on its Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence to a
prior distribution with a mean vector µ0 and an identity
covariance matrix I"

Can someone explain this to me. What should I know to understand this part.

EDIT 1:
can u help me understand this equation?

p(µ, Σ) = exp[−φ · KL(Q(µ, Σ)||Q(µ0, I))]. Equation 3 in the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may give you some intuition about the KL divergence and describe why you see this notation. In general, KL divergence is a measure of dissimilarity between distributions.

Let's understand its formula:
Consider an event $x$ (e.x. $x$: a comet hits the earth tonight), then the probability of the even happening is $p(x)$. If I share the event $x$ with you, then the importance of the information or the **Information** (this is how it is called in ML or Statistics) is given by the following expression:

$$ I_p(x) = - \log{p(x)} $$

If the probability of $x$ is low then the information is huge. If the probability of the event is huge (e.x. $x$ : if you heat water, it boils, then $p(x) = 1$ ) the information is very low.

It's not only how important the information of an event is, it is also how likely the event is to happen. This is called **Entropy**. The formula for a distribution (many events such as $x_a$ : a comet hits the earth tonight, $x_b$ : It will rain in London tomorrow, etc..) is given by the following:

$$ H = \sum_{x}p(x)I_p(x) =- \sum_{x} p(x)log(x) $$

Note that the information in the expression above, is weighted by the probability function $p$. You probably might give different probabilities about the events $x$ so your probability distribution is $q$. We want to know how different your probability distribution is to mine, considering the information of an event. Then the **KL Divergence** is given by the following expression:

$$ KL (p||q) =  \sum_{x}p(x)I_p(x) - \sum_{x}p(x)I_q(x) \\
= - \sum_{x} p(x)\log{p(x)} + \sum_{x} p(x)\log{q(x)} $$

It holds that:

$\bullet$ $KL(p(x)||q(x)) \geqslant 0$

$\bullet$ $KL(p(x)||q(x)) \neq KL(q(x)||p(x))$

In the paper that you just showed, the probabilities are multivariate (more than one dimension) and this is why you see the **μ, Σ** notations. I will first show you the formula of a univariate Gaussian distribution and then the formula for a multivariate so that you may understand how the formula works.

Univariate:

$$N(x|μ, σ^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πσ^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-μ)^2}{2σ^2}}$$

Multivariate:

$$N(x|μ, Σ) = \frac{1}{|2πΣ|}\exp{\Big[-\frac{1}{2}(x-μ)^ΤΣ^{-1}(x-μ)\Big]}$$

If $μ$ is a d dimensional array, $Σ$ is the covariance matrix with $d\times d$ dimensions.

Comment: can u help me understand this equation? p(µ, Σ) = exp[−φ · KL(Q(µ, Σ)||Q(µ0, I))]. Equation 3 in the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply though. It gave me a nice intuition for KL divergence.

Comment: $KL(Q(μ,Σ)||(Q(μ_0,Ι))$ is a number greater or equal to zero. If the distributions $Q(μ,Σ)$ and $Q(μ_0,Ι)$ are very dissimilar then $KL$ gets bigger and  $\exp{-φ KL}$ gets smaller as well as $p(μ,Σ)$. $φ$ is a weight factor so that you can further punish ($φ>1$), or diminish ($φ<1$) the dissimilarity between the distributions.

The main idea of this expression is that you want the distributions produced by $μ$,$Σ$ and $μ_0$, $Ι$ to be as similar as possible.

Comment: that is not the multivariate Normal density.

Comment: It is the multivariate normal distribution as I said, according to this [link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc542.htm) and according to the "Bayesian Methods in Machine Learning" course in coursera at this [link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-methods-in-machine-learning/lecture/p1FM9/linear-regression) at 01:40.